# How to get common data from same table with different conditions in c# or sql

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 tables, one table consist of Items having columns itemID, name

other table is Location having columns as ItemID, LocationID
Each Item can have multiple locations 
For eg:  I have 3 items Mouse, Keyboard, Speaker

- Mouse is there in 4 locations - A,B,C,D
- Keyboard is there in 2 locations - A,C
- Speaker is there in 3 locations - A,B,C

Now i want to have a code in c# or sql which will give me common locations of all the 3 items i.e A in the current example.

Comment: search for DTO(Data Transfer Objects)

Comment: @Sona . . . Both A and C are common to all three items.

Comment: Relational division is always so much fun! Too bas there is close to no builtin operator for this in RDBMSs. (or maybe my skills are dated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select l.locationid
from locations l
group by l.locationid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from items);
```

This assumes that the rows are unique in `locations`.  Otherwise, use `count(distinct itemid)`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=004934855eac3a9c6f7d936f17454670) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that it works.

Comment: @Sona . . . I added a db<>fiddle showing that it works.

Comment: check the fiddle now <https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a7cefd15de22d4ffe7d7c45db09e4411>

Comment: @Sona . . . If you change the logic by adding a `WHERE` clause, then you should expect to break the code.  This answers -- and answers correctly -- the question that you asked.  If you have another question, then ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: @Sona : Gordon is right - but more constructively, your WHERE clause should be added to both selects to work (inside and outside the HAVING clause)

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry my mistake, i am new to stack so dont know how it worked,  i just gave one example

Answer (score 0):

Try LINQ union:

```
int[] ints1 = { 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 9, 3, 7 };
int[] ints2 = { 8, 3, 6, 4, 4, 9, 1, 0 };

IEnumerable<int> union = ints1.Union(ints2);
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Locations TABLE (
ItemId INT,
Location VARCHAR(5)
)


DECLARE @Items TABLE (
ItemId INT,
Name VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Items (ItemId,Name)VALUES(1,'Mouse')
INSERT INTO @Items (ItemId,Name)VALUES(2,'Keyboard')
INSERT INTO @Items (ItemId,Name)VALUES(3,'Speaker')


INSERT INTO @Locations (ItemId,Location) VALUES(1, 'A')
INSERT INTO @Locations (ItemId,Location) VALUES(1, 'B')
INSERT INTO @Locations (ItemId,Location) VALUES(1, 'C')
INSERT INTO @Locations (ItemId,Location) VALUES(1, 'D')

INSERT INTO @Locations (ItemId,Location) VALUES(2, 'A')
INSERT INTO @Locations (ItemId,Location) VALUES(2, 'C')

INSERT INTO @Locations (ItemId,Location) VALUES(3, 'A')
INSERT INTO @Locations (ItemId,Location) VALUES(3, 'B')
INSERT INTO @Locations (ItemId,Location) VALUES(3, 'C')
INSERT INTO @Locations (ItemId,Location) VALUES(3, 'C')


SELECT List.Location FROM (
SELECT l.Location,l.ItemId
from @Locations l
GROUP by l.Location,l.ItemId) List
GROUP by List.Location
having count(List.Location) = (select count(*) from @Items);
```

Can you try this?

Comment: Why should he try this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PIVOT in SQL Server, maybe it can works for you.

```
CREATE TABLE #items (
  ID_item int,
  name varchar(20)
)
CREATE TABLE #item_location (
  ID_item int,
  ID_location char(1)
)

INSERT INTO #items( ID_item, name ) VALUES (1,'Mouse')
INSERT INTO #items( ID_item, name ) VALUES (2,'Keyboard')
INSERT INTO #items( ID_item, name ) VALUES (3,'Speaker')

INSERT INTO #item_location (ID_item, ID_location) VALUES (1,'A')
INSERT INTO #item_location (ID_item, ID_location) VALUES (1,'B')
INSERT INTO #item_location (ID_item, ID_location) VALUES (1,'C')
INSERT INTO #item_location (ID_item, ID_location) VALUES (1,'D')
INSERT INTO #item_location (ID_item, ID_location) VALUES (2,'A')
INSERT INTO #item_location (ID_item, ID_location) VALUES (2,'C')
INSERT INTO #item_location (ID_item, ID_location) VALUES (3,'A')
INSERT INTO #item_location (ID_item, ID_location) VALUES (3,'B')
INSERT INTO #item_location (ID_item, ID_location) VALUES (3,'C')


--SELECT B.ID_location, COUNT(1) 
--FROM #items AS A
--INNER JOIN #item_location AS B ON A.ID_item = B.ID_Item
--GROUP BY B.ID_Location;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(200);

SET @columns = STUFF(
     (
     SELECT
       ','+ QUOTENAME(LTRIM(name))
     FROM
       (SELECT DISTINCT
         A.name
        FROM #items AS A
       ) AS T 
     FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 1, '')

 SET @sql = N'
  SELECT
   * 
  FROM
  (  
  SELECT  ID_location,name
  FROM #item_location A INNER JOIN #items B ON B.ID_item = A.ID_item 
  ) AS T
  PIVOT   
  (
  count(name)
  FOR name IN (' + @columns + N')
  ) AS P order by ID_location;'; 

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

  DROP TABLE #item_location
  DROP TABLE #items
```

Comment: Output of the above query is 
ID_location Keyboard    Mouse       Speaker
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
A           1           1           1
B           0           1           1
C           1           1           1
D           0           1           0


but i want only common location for all the items, in the current example it is A

Comment: Ohh, I understand it, you can use group by for the ID_location and ORDER BY for have a ranking for comun location, I copied my code to SQL fiddle if someone wants to prove another results, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ed56e/33